# Is there a way to set the id of an existing instance as the value of a nested serializer in DRF?

Tags: json, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I'm developing a chat application. I have a serializer like this:

```
class PersonalChatRoomSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = PersonalChatRoom
        fields = '__all__'
    
    user_1 = UserSerializer(read_only=True)
    user_2 = UserSerializer()
```

the `user_1` field is auto-populated but the client should provide the `user_2` field in order to create a personal chat room with another user.

My problem is, when creating a new chat room, the serializer tries to create a new user object from the input data thus giving me validation errors. What I really want it to do is to accept a user `id` and set the value of `user_2` field to an **existing user instance that is currently available in the database** and if the user is not found, simply return a validation error. (the exact behavior of `PrimaryKeyRelatedField` when creating a new object)

I want my input data to look like this:

```
{
    'user_2': 1 // id of the user
}
```

And when I retrieve my `PersonalChatRoom` object, I want the serialized form of the user object for my `user_2` field:

```
{
    ...,
    'user_2': {
         'username': ...,
         'the_rest_of_the_fields': ...
    }
}
```

How can I achieve this?

## views.py

```
class GroupChatRoomViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = [IsUserVerified, IsGroupOrIsAdminOrReadOnly]
    serializer_class = GroupChatRoomSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.request.user.group_chat_rooms.all()

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        return serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured out how to do it. I just needed to override the `to_representation` method and serialize the object there. Here is the code I ended up with:

```
class PersonalChatRoomSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = PersonalChatRoom
        fields = '__all__'
        read_only_fields = ['user_1']

    def to_representation(self, chat_room):
        """ Serialize user instances when outputing the results """
        obj = super().to_representation(chat_room)
        for field in obj.keys():
            if field.startswith('user_'):
                obj[field] = UserSerializer(User.objects.get(pk=obj[field])).data
        return obj
```